# metamask sdk v0.2.4 cant not catch error when reject connect wallet on react native

Tags: metamask, ethers.js, dapps

I develop dapp with react native 0.71.4.

I want to connect wallet in my dapp, I install metamask/sdk 0.2.4

if i reject connection, try catch doesnt know request has been rejected.

here is my code

```typescript
const connect = async () => {
    try {
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
      const address = provider.send('eth_requestAccounts', []);
      console.log('address', address);
    } catch (err) {
      console.debug('err', err);
    }
  };
```

I use ethers too.

if there is another way to connect metamask without metamask/sdk, let me know.

thank you !

p.s. I try to use walletconnet/web3Wallet. It doesnt support metamask yet.